# Как сохранить нажатия на экран android с помощью kivy?

Tags: android, python, android-scrollview, kivy, touch-event

Здравствуйте! Пишу приложение под android на python, используя kivy. Мне нужно, чтобы все движения по экрану сохранялись в файл. Для этого я обрабатываю события :

- def on_touch_down(self, touch):
- def on_touch_move(self, touch):
- def on_touch_up(self, touch):

Общая схема такая:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    //сохранить touch.x и touch.y
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    //сохранить touch.x и touch.y
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    //сохранить touch.x и touch.y
```

Однако при этом события кнопок или скролл перестают работать, напрмер:

```
def on_click(self):
    //обработать нажатие на кнопку
```

Оно и логично, так как on touch down перехватил нажатие раньше и обрабатывает.

Но как сделать чтобы событие кнопки тоже срабатывало?
Можно ли запустить фоновый процесс, который будет получать все движения из моего приложения?
Или возможно как-то сделать, чтобы после обработки события в `on_touch_down/move/up()` событие прокидывалось дальше в `on_click()` или в скролл?

Конечно можно проверять координаты точки и соответствуют ли области какой-то кнопки, но как тогда быть для скролла, придется сохранять и сопоставлять траекторию каждого движения.

Comment: Что вы такое несете??? В чем вопрос? А том ли, что вы не можете сохранить данные функций on_touch_move/down/up или же в том, что вы не можете обработать события в  on_click?

Comment: Повежливее будь. Вопрос в том, что после установки обработчиков on_touch_move/down/up событие on_click не срабатывает.

Comment: А событие on_click, стало быть, какого виджета? Что такое on_click, где вы его взяли?